# Counting date based on month excluding hyphen

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, count

I have number of tasks assigned to me in Excel sheet (Sheet name: Status) where i enter closed date in column AC. I want to count closed tasks based on month and year of closing. But i have many tasks not closed and i enter in the corresponding cell(in column AC) with hyphen(-). I use the following formula to count the number of task closed.

**`SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Status!$AC$1:$AC$100)=MONTH(DATEVALUE(G21&" 1")))*(YEAR(Status!$AC$1:$ACA$100)=2020))`**

If cells from AC1 to AC100 are entered with date, the formula works. But when i have task not closed i enter hyphen(-) in some cells(between AC1 to AC100) the formula returns the error **#VALUE!**

Can you please help how to count closed tasks based on month and year in the range ***AC1:AC100*** excluding hyphens with a formula in a cell(H21). I have month name(format: MMM) in another sheet starts from G21. Formula entered in H21.

Comment: Please post an image to make it more clear what you have and what you want.

Comment: Should `YEAR(Status!$AC$1:$ACA$100)=2020` actually be `YEAR(Status!$AC$1:$AC$100)=2020` i.e. columns `AC` NOT `ACA`?

Comment: @JohnF: Sorry that was a typing error. Range is AC1:AC100

Comment: @ExcelHero: sorry i couldn't image in the comment. I don't know how to add image

Answer (score 0):

The `#VALUE` error occurs because the `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions expect a serial date as the argument. By using a -, which is text, the `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions return a `#VALUE` error, which causes the rest of the formula to return `#VALUE`.

You could use a blank cell instead of "-" for open tasks, and your formula will work. If you MUST use "-", then first modify the "-" using, for example, an array `IF`:

`=SUMPRODUCT((IF($AC$1:$AC$100="-",0,MONTH($AC$1:$AC$100))=MONTH(DATEVALUE(G21&" 1")))*(IF($AC$1:$AC$100="-",0,YEAR($AC$1:$AC$100))=2020))`

EDIT Ihave added an image of the formula working below:
 [image]

Comment: Sorry your formula returns value 0. I tried with and without hyphens in my selected range. Kindly can you check yourself too?

Comment: Oh you might need the sheet name in front of the cell references: `=SUMPRODUCT((IF(Status!$AC$1:$AC$100="-",0,MONTH(Status!$AC$1:$AC$100))=MONTH(DATEVALUE(G21&" 1")))*(IF(Status!$AC$1:$AC$100="-",0,YEAR(Status!$AC$1:$AC$100))=2020))`

Comment: In fact i already tried with sheet name. Same result (0) was giving. Kindly can you check in your system with this formula? If it works?

Comment: Maybe try using Evaluate Formula in the Formulas tab to see why yours gives 0.